# Change font size or theme across entire application - Adobe Flex / AIR

Tags: apache-flex, blackberry, air, adobe

I am creating an Adobe Flex application for the Blackberry Playbook. I was wondering if there is a way where the user can click a button (for example) to increase or decrease all font sizes across the entire application?

Also a similar button to change the entire theme would be most useful! Is it possible?

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change dynamically styles as if you were changing it in your CSS:

```
var selector:CSSStyleDeclaration = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.styleManager.getStyleDeclaration("global");
selector.setStyle("fontSize", 8);
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.styleManager.setStyleDeclaration("global", selector, true);
```